# Unusual behavior of Intellisense in VB.Net 2017 in IF statements

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Note: it is quite possible that I am being an idiot about this issue.  If so, I apologize in advance.  I did some looking (here and on other sites) and didn't see an answer.  Perhaps I didn't properly phrase my search terms.  Again, my apologies.

This behavior I am seeing started with VS 2017 and did not happen in prior versions of VS.

What happens is when I am typing an IF statement in VB.Net 2017, Intellisense and auto-complete either does not happen or changes my input to something completely different, and very un-helpful.  To get back to the functionality I would expect, I have to stop what I am typing and space over and type:  )then  and press Enter.  Then, when I go back into the body of the IF statement to specify the test condition, Intellisense and auto-complete work as expected, and as they did in previous versions of VS.

Is anyone else having this issue?  Is there something that I can do (switch setting, etc.) to get rid of this annoyance?  I would have to imagine that there is a setting somewhere that would fix this that I am unaware of.

Thanks in advance,

Bob Kiser

Comment: Is the change consistent? Have you possibly mapped 'if' to some other completion text?

Comment: `I have to stop what I am typing and space over and type: )then and press Enter.` - Are you attempting a style like this: `If(a=5)Then` (i.e.: no spacing)?  If so, I can confirm the annoying VS help that you are getting.  If you enter a space after `If` it gets better.

Comment: Your description is far too vague.  Please explain EXACTLY what you are doing, EXACTLY what you expect to happen and EXACTLY what does happen.  If it does relate to the comment by @TnTinMn then my guess would be that it thinks that you're trying to use an `If` operator, in which the `If` keyword is followed directly by an opening parenthesis, rather than an `If` statement, in which the `If` keyword is followed by a space.

Comment: To TnTinMn:  Thanks for confirming that I am not crazy.  Yes, I am typing it like you suggest.  I will try entering a space like you suggest and see how that works for me.  it does seem like an annoyance that MS could fix w/o a lot of trouble and get back to the behavior I saw in prior VS releases.  To Andrew Mortimer:  Yes, consistent.  I have not done any mapping of any sort (that I know if, anyway).  Thanks to both of you for your comments.